# Material / texture are not showing up correctly?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have downloaded this file of a space craft from the NASA website, and every time I try to put the correct texture on the craft it won't work. In the pictures I attempted to use the Material in a cycles render, and then add an image texture. It worked and you can see the texture, but only in Texture view. When I switch to render view, the texture does not show.

[image]

Comment: Did you add your textures to a material?

Comment: no ,how do i do that ?!